# convert eigen matrix into std::vector<std::array<>> form

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, vector, eigen

How can I convert an Eigen matrix into `std::vector<std::array<>>` form? Suppose I have an Eigen matrix `Eigen::MatrixXd A(4,3)`. Is it possible to convert matrix A in `std::vector<std::array<double,3>>` form?

Comment: You need to create a loop and copy the values, there's no direct conversion possible.

Comment: I didn't quite get it. Can you please tell me what do you mean by copy?

Comment: _"what do you mean by copy?"_ Accessing each value from the `Eigen::MatrixXd` and copy it to the `std::vector<std::array<double,3>>`.

Comment: ohhh.. got it. You meant insert element by element. Thanks :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can map the memory of a `std::vector<std::array<double,3>>` to a writable Eigen type using `Eigen::Map`, e.g.,

```
// typedef for brevity, if you need this more often: 
typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> Mat43dR;

std::vector<std::array<double,3>> raw_data;
raw_data.resize(4); // allocate memory for 4x3 entries
// Copy A to raw_data:
Mat43dR::Map(raw_data[0].data() ) = A;
```

You can also read from `raw_data` using `Eigen::Map`, of course. And there are some alternative ways to work with `Eigen::Map`: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html

**Addendum**: If you don't know the size of `A` at compile-time, you can work with `Dynamic` sizes like so:

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> MatXXdR;
std::vector<std::array<double,3>> raw_data; // the `3` must still be known at compile-time
assert(A.cols()==3);
raw_data.resize(A.rows()); // allocate memory for Nx3 entries
// Copy A to raw_data:
MatXXdR::Map(raw_data[0].data(), A.rows(), A.cols() ) = A;
```

Comment: I was trying to define the matrix in this way `typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, A.rows(), A.cols(), Eigen::RowMajor> Mat43dR;` but getting error. Is there any way to define the matrix without hardcodnig the size?

Comment: Your question was explicitly about a `4x3` matrix, but I added an alternative, if you don't know these. Still, for `std::array` you need to know the dimension at compile-time.

Comment: You could create a ```std::vector<std::vector<double>>``` This way you would have a dynamically sized 2d vector of doubles.